# How intercept page creation in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

It is needed to call `setVersioned(false)` to all pages in application. Is there a way to call this method from, say, IComponentInstantiationListener, which calls such method whenever new page is created?

P.S. It is possible to create a base class and use it everywhere, but it lead to modify all page classes :(

Comment: I cannot imagine bigger Wicket application without base class & exnteds. It is  very natural process. with many benefits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `application.getPageSettings().setVersioned(false)`.

Check how Page#isVesioned() works.